# Skipping over some input - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, constructor, java.util.scanner

I'm doing small exercise on Java. I need to enter three details of 3 movies(title, genre and rating) and then get them to display.

So basically I have to write appropriate getter and setter methods for each of the private data members and should also write an appropriate constructor the application that  include a tester/driver class, which creates three instances of the Movie class and stores them in an array. The tester class should use a for loop to set the title, genre and rating of the Movie objects. Should also use a for loop that should traverse the array and display the title, genre and rating for each element of the array and call the playIt() method for each object.

so far here's my code for movie.class and movieTester.class

```
public class Movie {

// Declare Private Variables

private String title;
private String genre;
private int rating;




// Default constructor
    public Movie() {

    }


    /// The constructors ///

    public Movie(String title,String genre, int rating) {
        this.title = title;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.rating = rating;

    }


    // Getter and setter methods

    public String getTitle() { // getTitle
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) { // SetTitle
        this.title = title;
    }


    public String getGenre() { // GetGenre
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) { // SetGenre
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public int getRating() { // GetRating
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(int rating) { // SetRating
        this.rating = rating;
    }



public void playIt(){
     System.out.println("Playing the Movie");
    }
```

}

And this is for MovieTester.class

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

public class MovieTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Create Scanner input


         // Populate using an array of Movie's

        Movie mymovie[] = new Movie[3];


        // Using for loop

         for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
             Movie movie = new Movie();


            // Enter Details For Movie
            System.out.println("Please Enter The Title Of Movie: ");
            String title = input.nextLine();
            movie.setTitle(title);

            System.out.println("Please Enter The Genre Of Movie: ");
            String genre = input.nextLine();
            movie.setGenre(genre);

            System.out.println("Please Enter The Rating Of Movie: ");
            int ret  = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
            movie.setRating(ret);

            System.out.println();

            mymovie[i] = movie;
        }





        // Using  for  loop o traverse the.
        // array and display the title, genre and rating,
        // for each element of the array


        for (int i = 0; i < mymovie.length; i++) {
            Movie movie = mymovie[i];

            System.out.println("Title: " + movie.getTitle());
            System.out.println("Genre: " + movie.getGenre());
            System.out.println("Rating: " + movie.getRating());
            mymovie[i].playIt();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }



    }
```

When I run it this is what I get:

```
    Please Enter The Title Of Movie: 
Harold and Kumar
Please Enter The Genre Of Movie: 
Comedy
Please Enter The Rating Of Movie: 
5

Please Enter The Title Of Movie: 
Please Enter The Genre Of Movie: 
Comedy
Please Enter The Rating Of Movie: 
4

Please Enter The Title Of Movie: 
Please Enter The Genre Of Movie: 
Action
Please Enter The Rating Of Movie: 
3

Title: Harold and Kumar
Genre: Comedy
Rating: 5
Playing the Movie

Title: 
Genre: Comedy
Rating: 4
Playing the Movie

Title: 
Genre: Action
Rating: 3
Playing the Movie
```

The issue with the output is that after entering the first full Movie details (title, genre and rating). It skipped entering movie 'title' (Second and Third) and only can enter genre and rating.

Its probably some issue with the 'for loop'. But can't figure it out. 
Can someone tell me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: In the line `int ret  = Integer.parseInt(input.next());` you are calling `next()` which does not consume the newline, and thus the next call to `nextLine()` captures an empty `String`

Comment: @GBlodgett
I got it working now.  
' int ret  = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()); ' 
Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.